# How to run React project

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have a project in React. It is cloned from Git-lab. I consist of two separate aplications: backend and frontend. Question is simple. How to run it? It should contain Laravel implementation but I dont see anythind inside. Is there any npm commant I need to run? I think npm create-react-app is not the right command of exisiting aplication. I am sorry for this trivial question. This is my first contact with React.

Comment: When in the root project (where the `package.json` file is ) of the react app run `npm run start` or `react-scripts start`. Do not forget to run `npm install` first. The application should be running on `localhost:3000`.

Comment: npm install throws me an errors e.g. npm ERR! iltorb@2.4.5 install: node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see `package-lock.json` file, try `npm install` and `npm start`. If there is `yarn.lock` file, try `yarn install` and `yarn start`. You need to run "install" command only once (and after change of `package.json`).

Comment: npm install throws me an errors e.g. npm ERR! iltorb@2.4.5 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

I open Git Bash command window and when it is at the correct directory type NPM START.  Being that you have both back and front end you would open two BASH windows and do this for each (backend first).

Answer (score -1):

it simple,first of all you open terminal and type a **npm run start** command.application running started. then all done you will display the url then you entered in your browser it work.